# Create Maven project with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, archetypes

i want to create a Maven project in eclipse. I have install the m2eclipse plugin in my eclipse, i have create a new Maven Project, now i'm stuck with archetype, i want to create a project with Struts 2, Hibernate 3, MySql and JUnit

Comment: About the same answer as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651715/archetype-hibernate-3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [archetype hibernate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651715/archetype-hibernate-3)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect to find an archetype for all possible combinations, they are endless and I generally prefer to shape my own project myself, starting with basic archetypes (you can bootstrap a project using some archetypes, just don't expect to always find an ultimate generic solution).

In your case, you could either use the [Struts 2 Blank Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-AvailableArchetypes) for the presentation part:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
                       -DgroupId=tutorial \
                       -DartifactId=tutorial \
                       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-blank \
                       -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.8.1
```

And then the JPA archetype (hibernate based) for the domain part:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
                       -DgroupId=com.my-company.my-project \
                       -DartifactId=my-project-domain \
                       -DpackageName=com.company.project.domain \
                       -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype  \
                       -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo \
                       -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0
```

---

Or use the [AppFuse QuickStart archetype](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart):

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
                       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-struts-archetype \
                       -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.0-M1 \
                       -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject
```

And remove all the appfuse specifc stuff (seems to be more work than going the other way i.e. adding stuff).

---

Or simply create a blank webapp and add the required stuff yourself. Often, this is the best thing to do as already hinted.

#### Resources

- [Archetypes List](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List)
- [AppFuse QuickStart archetype](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart)
- [Struts 2 Maven Archetypes](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html)